# 'GeneralInformation': cannot reference a type through an expression; try 'WebQuoter.Models.Chiller.GeneralInformation' instead

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, types, reference, expression

I have the following model:

```
namespace WebQuoter.Models
{
    public class Chiller
    {
        public class GeneralInformation
        {
            public string AssemblyID { get; set; }
            public string Model { get; set; }
            public string Series { get; set; }
            public string Revision { get; set; }
            public string Application { get; set; }
            public string PreviousAssyID { get; set; }
            public bool AvailbleInQuoter { get; set; }
            public bool NeedsUpdates { get; set; }
            public bool Obsolete { get; set; }
            public string EngineeringWorkRequestNo { get; set; }
            public string Customer { get; set; }
            public string CustomerMachineModel { get; set; }
            public string CustomerPartNumber { get; set; }
            public string PrimaryVoltage { get; set; }
            public string SecondaryVoltage { get; set; }
            public string GeneralNotes { get; set; }
            public string ChillerNotes { get; set; }
        }
        public class Cooling
        {
            public string Refrigerant { get; set; }
            public string RefrigerantCapacity { get; set; }
            public string CompressorType { get; set; }
            public string CompressorHP { get; set; }
            public string CondenserType { get; set; }
            public string Fan { get; set; }
        }
        public class FluidCircuit
        {
            public class PrimaryCircuit
            {
                public string CoolingCapacity { get; set; }
                public string FlowRate { get; set; }
                public string PumpPressure { get; set; }
            }
            public class SecondaryCircuit
            {
                public string CoolingCapacity { get; set; }
                public string FlowRate { get; set; }
                public string PumpPressure { get; set; }
            }
            public string FluidTemperature { get; set; }
            public string TemperatureStability { get; set; }
            public string SensorLocation { get; set; }
            public string PumpHorsePower { get; set; }
            public string CoolingMedium { get; set; }
            public string TankCapacity { get; set; }
            public string TankMaterialOfConstruction { get; set; }
            public string TankType { get; set; }
            public string FluidConnections { get; set; }
            public string FluidConnectionsSize { get; set; }
            public string FluidConnectionsUnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
            public string WettedComponentMaterial { get; set; }
            public string Evaporator { get; set; }
            public string GaugeType { get; set; }
        }
        public class ClimateData
        {
            public string SiteOfInstallation { get; set; }
            public string AmbientConditions { get; set; }
            public string SoundLevel { get; set; }
        }
        public class Controller
        {
            public class PrimaryVoltage
            {
                public string Voltage { get; set; }
                public string Phases { get; set; }
                public string Frequency { get; set; }
                public string ControlVoltage { get; set; }
            }
            public class SecondaryVoltage
            {
                public string Voltage { get; set; }
                public string Phases { get; set; }
                public string Frequency { get; set; }
            }
            public class CertificationsStandards
            {
                public string UL1995 { get; set; }
                public string CE { get; set; }
                public string NFPA79 { get; set; }
                public string CSA { get; set; }
                public string UL508A { get; set; }
                public string AdditionalCertifications { get; set; }
            }
            public string FullLoadedAmps { get; set; }
            public string DisconnectFuseSize { get; set; }
            public string FalseSignalAlarm { get; set; }
            public string ControllerType { get; set; }
        }
        public class AdditionalData
        {
            public string WidthAirInletSideWithIncludedOptions { get; set; }
            public string DepthWithIncludedOptions { get; set; }
            public string HeightWithIncludedOptions { get; set; }
            public string Finish { get; set; }
            public string CratedWeight { get; set; }
            public string WetWeight { get; set; }
            public string ExportWeight { get; set; }
        }
        public class Features
        {
            public string BypassType { get; set; }
            public string FluidFilter { get; set; }
            public string FlowSwitch { get; set; }
            public string FluidLevelSwitch { get; set; }
            public string AutoMakeUp { get; set; }
            public string CapacityControl { get; set; }
            public string AntiBackFlow { get; set; }
            public string FluidHeater { get; set; }
            public string RefrigerantSightGlass { get; set; }
            public string AmbientTracking { get; set; }
            public string FeetCasters { get; set; }
            public string FillPort { get; set; }
            public string TankLevelSightGlass { get; set; }
            public string RefrigerantFilterDryer { get; set; }
            public string AirFilter { get; set; }
            public string WireConnection { get; set; }
            public string RemoteControls { get; set; }
            public string SpecialFeatures { get; set; }
            public string NominalCondensorSize { get; set; }
            public string FluidSetPointRange { get; set; }
            public string NominalCoilSize { get; set; }
            public string NomalBTUPerHour { get; set; }
            public string CabinetType { get; set; }
            public string Tank { get; set; }
            public string SaltwaterPackage { get; set; }
            public string HeaderSize { get; set; }
            public string PanelType { get; set; }
            public string SwitchoverType { get; set; }
            public string Pump { get; set; }
            public string PumpCurve { get; set; }
            public string HeatRejectionType { get; set; }
            public string NumberOfFluidCircuits { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

And the following controller code to access this model:

```
using Jitbit.Utils;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using WebQuoter.Models;

namespace WebQuoter.BusinessLayer
{

        public Chiller ParseValues(List<string> Values)
        {
            Chiller retVal = new Chiller();

            foreach(string value in Values)
            {
                string[] seperated = Regex.Split(value, "{EPDMSEPERATOR}");

                switch (seperated[0])
                {
                    case "07":
                        retVal.GeneralInformation.AssemblyID = "";
                        break;
                }
            }

            return retVal;
        }
    }
}
```

In the following line:

```
retVal.GeneralInformation.AssemblyID = "";
```

I get the error:

> 'GeneralInformation': cannot reference a type through an expression;
>   try 'WebQuoter.Models.Chiller.GeneralInformation' instead.

Everywhere I have seen is saying not to use the keyword Static. I am not using a static reference to this custom class anywhere.

Any help would be VERY much appreciated!

Comment: You've created nested classes, but the `Chiller` does not contain any `GeneralInformation` instances. You need to create a property that holds an instance of `GeneralInformation` to be able to access it, you can't stick information in a class without an instance of it if its not static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is you have nested classes but no instances, for example:

```
public class TopLevel
{
    public class InsideClass
    {
        public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Unless `InsideClass` is `static`, you can't access `SomeProperty`. You need to create an instance of the class:

```
public class TopLevel
{
    public class InsideClass
    {
        public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }
    public InsideClass MyInsideClass { get; set; }

    public TopLevel()
    {
        MyInsideClass = new InsideClass();
    }
}
```

Now you can access `SomeProperty` through an instance:

```
var myOutside = new TopLevel();
myOutside.MyInsideClass.SomeProperty = "Some Value";
```

Creating a nested class does not automatically make the nested class a `Member` of the outer class.

Comment: Thanks, that works great. I had a bit of editing to do for each nested class, but it worked!